# Android HttpUrlConnection fails with 400 response after a few hundred success responses

Tags: android, httpurlconnection

I'm using HttpUrlConnection in my android app. I'm trying to send a post request to a particular url every 2 seconds. Below is the code for the same.

The issue I have is, I get 200 OK response for the first approx 200-250 calls, and after that every call starts failing with

## 400 Bad request

Your browser sent an invalid request.

I force stop my app, and then as mentioned above the first 200-250 hits to my url comes with 200 OK and then starts failing with 400. I was able to reproduce this consistently every time. I tried almost like 10 times and the same thing happens.

**When I tried AndroidHttpClient I was able to make close to like 15000 hits to the same url without a single failure, so definitely not a server issue.**

I'm trying to understand what is the issue with httpUrlConnection, as I would like to stick with httpUrlConnection as it is recommended by Google. As far as I see I have done all error handling fine. 
I even tried to set http.keepAlive System property to false at the start of my appln/ included connection "Close" header before making the connection but nothing helped.

Could someone help me understand what am I doing wrong here?

```
        HttpURLConnection con = null;
        final BufferedReader rd = null;
        final BufferedOutputStream wr = null;
        final InputStreamReader isr = null;
        ServerConnectionData serverConnectionData = null;
        try {
                serverConnectionData = (ServerConnectionData) connectionData;
                final String urlPath = serverConnectionData.getUrlPath();
                final URL url = new URL(urlPath);
                trust();

                HttpsURLConnection.setDefaultHostnameVerifier(new NullHostNameVerifier());
                final URLConnection urlConnection = url.openConnection();
                con = (HttpURLConnection) urlConnection;
                con.setRequestMethod("POST");
                // con.addRequestProperty("Connection", "Keep-Alive");
                // con.addRequestProperty("Connection", "Close");                   

                if (serverConnectionData.getJsonData() != null) {
                    con.addRequestProperty(
                            "Content-Length",
                            Integer.toString(serverConnectionData.getJsonData().getBytes(
                                    Charset.forName("UTF8")).length));
                }
                if (serverConnectionData.getAdditionalHeaders() != null) {
                    final Map<String, String> additionalHeaders =
                            serverConnectionData.getAdditionalHeaders();
                    final Set<String> keySet = additionalHeaders.keySet();
                    for (final Object key : keySet) {
                        con.addRequestProperty((String) key, additionalHeaders.get(key));
                    }
                }

                final String authToken = "Bearer " +  "my outh token";
                con.addRequestProperty("Authorization", authToken);
                con.addRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json; charset=UTF-8");

                con.setUseCaches(false);
                con.setConnectTimeout(60000);
                con.setDoInput(true);
                con.setDoOutput(true);

                con.connect();

                sendData(con, serverConnectionData);

                responseCode = con.getResponseCode();
                responseText = getResponseText(con);

                if (responseCode == 200) {
                    // success
                } else {
                    // failure                      }
                }

        } catch (final MalformedURLException e) {
            throw new ConnectionException(ErrorCodes.SERVER_CONNECTION_ERROR, e.getStackTrace());
        } catch (final IOException e) {
            Log.e(e.toString());
            try {
                if (null != con) {
                    responseCode = con.getResponseCode();
                    responseText = getResponseText(con);
                }
                if (responseCode == 401) {
                    // handle 401 response
                } else {
                    final ConnectionException ce =
                            new ConnectionException(ErrorCodes.SERVER_CONNECTION_ERROR,
                                    e.getStackTrace());
                    ce.setResponseCode(responseCode);
                    throw ce;
                }
            } catch (final UnsupportedEncodingException uee) {
                throw new ConnectionException(ErrorCodes.SERVER_CONNECTION_ERROR,
                        uee.getStackTrace());
            } catch (final IOException ioe) {
                throw new ConnectionException(ErrorCodes.SERVER_CONNECTION_ERROR,
                        ioe.getStackTrace());
            }

        } catch (final KeyManagementException e) {
            throw new ConnectionException(ErrorCodes.SERVER_CONNECTION_ERROR, e.getStackTrace());
        } catch (final NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
            throw new ConnectionException(ErrorCodes.SERVER_CONNECTION_ERROR, e.getStackTrace());
        } catch (final Exception e) {
            throw new ConnectionException(ErrorCodes.SERVER_CONNECTION_ERROR, e.getStackTrace());
        } finally {
            if (wr != null) {
                try {
                    wr.flush();
                    wr.close();
                } catch (final IOException e) {
                    throw new ConnectionException(ErrorCodes.SERVER_CONNECTION_ERROR,
                            e.getStackTrace());
                }

            }
            if (isr != null) {
                try {
                    isr.close();
                } catch (final IOException e) {
                    throw new ConnectionException(ErrorCodes.SERVER_CONNECTION_ERROR,
                            e.getStackTrace());
                }

            }
            if (rd != null) {
                try {
                    rd.close();
                } catch (final IOException e) {
                    throw new ConnectionException(ErrorCodes.SERVER_CONNECTION_ERROR,
                            e.getStackTrace());
                }

            }
            if (con != null) {
                con.disconnect();
            }
        }


private void trust() throws NoSuchAlgorithmException, KeyManagementException {

    final TrustManager[] trustAllCerts = new TrustManager[] {
        new X509TrustManager() {
            @Override
            public java.security.cert.X509Certificate[] getAcceptedIssuers() {
                return null;
            }

            @Override
            public void checkClientTrusted(final java.security.cert.X509Certificate[] certs,
                    final String authType) {
            }

            @Override
            public void checkServerTrusted(final java.security.cert.X509Certificate[] certs,
                    final String authType) {
            }
        }
    };

    final SSLContext sc = SSLContext.getInstance("SSL");
    sc.init(null, trustAllCerts, new java.security.SecureRandom());
    HttpsURLConnection.setDefaultSSLSocketFactory(sc.getSocketFactory());

}

public void sendData(final HttpURLConnection con, final ServerConnectionData serverConnectionData)
        throws IOException, ConnectionException {

    final String requestJSON = serverConnectionData.getJsonData();
    if (requestJSON != null) {
        BufferedOutputStream bufferedOutputStream = null;
        try {
            bufferedOutputStream = new BufferedOutputStream(con.getOutputStream());
            bufferedOutputStream.write(requestJSON.getBytes());
            bufferedOutputStream.flush();
        } finally {
            if (bufferedOutputStream != null) {
                try {
                    bufferedOutputStream.flush();
                    bufferedOutputStream.close();
                } catch (final IOException e) {
                    setOnlineStatus(ONLINE_STATUS_BAD);
                    throw new ConnectionException(ErrorCodes.SERVER_CONNECTION_ERROR,
                            e.getStackTrace());
                }

            }
        }
    }
}

 public String getResponseText(final HttpURLConnection con) throws IOException {

    InputStream stream = null;
    InputStreamReader inputStreamReader = null;
    BufferedReader bufferedReader = null;
    String responseText = null;
    try {
        final int responseCode = con.getResponseCode();
        if (200 == responseCode) {
            stream = con.getInputStream();
        }
        if (null == stream) {
            stream = con.getErrorStream();
        }
        if (null == stream) {
            return "";
        }
        inputStreamReader = new InputStreamReader(stream, "UTF8");
        bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(inputStreamReader);
        final StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder("");
        String line;
        while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
            sb.append(line);
        }
        responseText = sb.toString();
    } finally {
        if (bufferedReader != null) {
            bufferedReader.close();
        }
        if (inputStreamReader != null) {
            inputStreamReader.close();
        }
        if (stream != null) {
            stream.close();
        }
    }
    return responseText;
}
```

Comment: What do your server logs show?

Comment: This is what I see in the server's squid cache.log file       2014/10/02 12:06:59| httpReadReply: Request not yet fully sent "POST https://myUrl”
2014/10/02 12:07:02| httpReadReply: Request not yet fully sent "POST  https://myUrl"
2014/10/02 12:07:04| httpReadReply: Request not yet fully sent "POST  https://myUrl"
2014/10/02 12:07:10| httpReadReply: Request not yet fully sent "POST  https://myUrl"
2014/10/02 12:07:10| httpSendRequestEntryDone: Likely proxy abuse detected ‘has my device IP address’ -> ' https://myUrl'

Comment: "Likely proxy abuse detected" suggests that your Squid server thinks that you are doing a denial-of-service attack or something.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help and response, but I don't face this issue when I use AndroidHttpClient like a said 15000-20000 hits go without a failure, but using httpUrlConnection it fails in the first 250 calls. I'm sorry I'm new to this, but could you please help me understand why the server would behave differently based on what the client is using(httpUrlconnection/androidhttpClient)

Comment: I have no idea, as I did not write your server app or configure your server environment.

Comment: I checked with my server team and their response is "The squid server doesn't have any per-client configuration or even recognition, it is a pure a HTTP server it just sees traffic, and the traffic it's getting from httpUrlConnection is apparently not following the HTTP standard. This pretty definitively narrows it down to a problem on the client" They also asked if we could disable pipelining for httpUrlConnection, My understanding is that httpurlConnection does not support pipelining. Is that right?

Comment: Sorry, I don't remember off the top of my head what pipelining is. Do bear in mind that there are at least two major implementations of `HttpUrlConnection` in Android. Android 4.4 uses OkHttp; prior versions of Android used stuff that originated with Apache Harmony but was modified over the years.

Comment: @Commonsware Thanks for the information. In my Application class I was doing  cookieManager = new CookieManager(new CustomCookieStore(), CookiePolicy.ACCEPT_ALL); CookieHandler.setDefault(cookieManager);
removed the above calls and all works fine.
I’m not doing anything at all with cookies(no headers/cookie handling etc) when interacting with server, but looks like httpUrlConnection obeys the cookies by default just by setting CookieHandler.setDefault(cookieManager);
Is it correct that this scenario will cause client httpUrlconnection to throw 400, meaning the session has expired?

Comment: Found these two links, that was relevant
[link](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/CookieManager.html)
[link](http://modernholo.com/services/http-requests/)